# How to set custom horizontal axis interval in SSRS chart? It always shows every other label

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report, confused on which version- somewhere between 2008-2014. I'm developing it in VS 2013. I have a chart with an x axis showing category groups, which is a date field displayed using an expression. I do not want it to show every date when there are a large amount, so I tried writing an expression for the Interval field like below to set the interval based on how many rows there are, but it always shows every other label. I will even just set the interval to simply 4 or 6 or 10 or whatever and it always shows every other label, as if the interval is 2.  I attached a screen shot to show where I'm changing it. If I change my parameters and run the chart for different data, it will show the interval as 1 sometimes. Maybe there's another place where the interval can be set?

[image]

3 different interval expressions I've tried

```
 =Ceiling(CountRows("GetAllStatusMeasureData") / 30)

  4

 =4

 "4"
```

Comment: Change the Axis type to Scalar. Select the Interval date type. Then you can set the interval and it will actually know what to do with it.

Comment: I should have been more specific that I was dealing with strings- the labels look something like "Jan-Mar 2008" or "May 2009"- they vary. However the underlying category grouping was done one a date field, so maybe I could have done this but if you see my answer, I changed a different interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a separate interval for the labels on the axis- I incorrectly assumed it was all the same. I looked at the Properties window for the Chart Axis and it showed a LabelIntervalOffset and that was the one I needed to change, not the Interval in the section called Interval. Screen shot below:

[image]